# Debugging embedded Python code in .Net app using Pythonnet and Pdb

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-5, pdb, python.net

I have a worker service in which I need to debug Python code. To execute Python code I need to use Pythonnet. Pdb module is used for debugging.
I'm trying something like that:

python.txt:

```
import pdb

def func():
    pdb.set_trace()
    //code for debugging...
```

C# code:

```
var pythonCode = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\python.txt");
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"D:\Python38\python38.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();

using (Py.GIL())
{
    var pyModule = Py.CreateScope("scope");
    pyModule.Exec(pythonCode);
}

Task.Run(() => 
    {
       using (Py.GIL())
       {
           pyModule.Exec("func()");
       }
    });

//some code
```

in Python code I call `pdb.set_trace()`, which waits for further debugger commands (n(ext), s(tep) etc.) to be entered into the console.
In C# code I execute the Python function in a different thread so as not to block the main thread of the service waiting for the command to be entered. If I input commands manually using VSCode's internal console, it works. But I need to pass debugger commands from the GUI through my worker service.

How can I pass these commands to standard input of executing python code from a service programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you spawn python subprocess and use standard i/o to communicate with it?

Comment: @freakish I tried your suggestion. I used `p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` and `p.communicate(script.encode('utf-8'))` but I can't interact with the subprocess interactively because process is terminate after sending the first command. I haven't interacted much with Python, so could you please point me to the correct direction? In one of the answers here I saw advice to try using `pexpect`

Comment: Wait, I don't understand. You are using C#. I'm not sure why, but if you have to run Python from C# then you can do it through [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) type. The docs will also tell you how to send data to the stdin and read from stdout. In other words: get rid of Pythonnet. I don't know that lib, and I couldn't find anything about stdin in the docs. I might have missed it though.

Comment: @freakish I considered the possibility of using Process type, but it is preferable to use Pythonnet. It has already been used in our codebase before. In our case the python script code is generated dynamically, and Pythonnet allows to quickly and conveniently execute partial code. I can set variable values in python code and get values from the executed script using pythonnet, but I don't understand how to interactively send values to standard input so that the pdb accepts them as debugger commands